# Keyboard shortcut to take me directly to Mission Control system preference pane

Tags: macos, keyboard, high-sierra, shortcut, mission-control

I have an iMac (27", 2017, High Sierra) and for various reasons I find myself often having to change my mission control settings.

As I prefer keyboard navigation., is there a native macOS keyboard shortcut that can take me straight to the  mission control preferences, or do I need to create one myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an Apple keyboard there’s no need to create a custom keyboard shortcut. The keyboard shortcut to take you immediately to the Mission Control system preference pane is <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Mission Control</kbd>.

**Note:** The <kbd>Mission Control</kbd> key on an Apple keyboard is the same key as the <kbd>F3</kbd> key.

Comment: Interesting! I have been using Macs for years and was unaware of this :)

Comment: Haha, yep, there's always something new to learn! :) Not a week goes by when I don't learn something new. So many hidden / undocumented things to find in any OS.

Comment: how do you map a pc keyboard to open mission control on a mac?